# Retrieve data from a plain file (Iphone development)

Tags: objective-c, ios4

In my personal of Iphone development project I need to retrieve data from plain txt file, afterwards using delimiter to separate data in the way I want.
It's my sample data:

```
100 100, 200 200, 300 300, 400 400
```

So how to retrieve data from `myfile.txt` and later retrieve the string "`100 100`" from this chunk of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

This is for getting the contents of the file. To seperate different pieces of data use this:

```
NSArray *items = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: there is no syntax error but seemingly I cant get the string out of NSLog().

Comment: Try NSLoging text string (if that's not what you have already done)